# How to use pipes (filters) with ionic2's virtualScroll

Tags: ionic2

I have a filter (pipe) that I want to use on a [`VirtualScroll`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll). Before I used the `VirtualScroll` I had a normal for-loop on `ion-item` using the formula:

`<ion-item *ngFor="#item of items | myPipe : criteria">....</ion-item>`

is it possible to use pipes with `<ion-item *virtualItem="#item" > ...</ion-item>` as well? Or do I have to do the pipe on the list in a controller instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using a pipe in the controller instead, creating a filteredItems list like so:

`filteredItems = new MyPipe().transform(this.items, ["criteria"]);`

Then, I display the filteredItems in the `VirtualScroll` instead of the original list:

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="filteredItems">
  <ion-item *virtualItem="#item">
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of usage of Pipe filters with angular rc3.

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="items | SearchPipe:searchBar | SortItems:orderType">
    <button ion-item *virtualItem="let item">
        <span [innerHtml]='item.Name | BoldPipe:searchbar'></span>
        <span [innerHtml]='item.Code | BoldPipe:searchbar'></span>
    </button>
</ion-list>
```

The pipe should be applied on the list instead of the item.

The answer posted by John (a good answer) but you'd have to activate it on every change detection rather than it being part of the rendering

Comment: I will try your solution and see if it works with my example. It is a better solution to use the filter directly on the list instead of maintaining a filteredList in the controller. There have been some updates in Angular 2 and Ionic since I posted the question as well.